# Please I am trying to concatenate string result to a variable in an express router but it returns an empty string

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, router

I am trying to iterate through the array get the value and search the database, then concatenate the database result to the string translation

```
app.get('/translate',function(req,res) {
  let translate = '';
  ['hello','love'].forEach(async (word) => {
  let trans = await 
  NaijaLang.find({"engword": word, "naijalang": "yoruba"});
    translate +=" " + trans[0].translation; 
    //Returns values
    console.log(translate)
  });

  //Returns Empty String;

  console.log(translate)
  res.send(translate);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you do some async stuff there, but you send the value synchronously. Basically, this code will run in this order:

1. run `let translate='';`
2. run `['hello','love'].forEach(...)`
3. run `await NaijaLang.find(...)` asynchronously for word=hello
4. run `await NaijaLang.find(...)` asynchronously for word=love
5. run `console.log(translate)` and `res.send(translate);`
6. resolve the value of `await NaijaLang.find(...)` -> this is the time when the `translate` is updated for the first time (either for word=hello or word=love. Whatever finishes earlier)
7. resolve the value of second call `await NaijaLang.find(...)` -> this is the time when the `translate` is updated for the second time. But the value was already send in the 5th step.

You can find more detailed explanation here: https://blog.lavrton.com/javascript-loops-how-to-handle-async-await-6252dd3c795

And you can also find there how to fix it. You can use the for-of loop instead of forEach:

```
app.get('/translate',function(req,res){
    let translate='';

    for (let word of ['hello','love']) {
        let trans=await NaijaLang.find({"engword":word,"naijalang":"yoruba"});
        translate+=" " + trans[0].translation; 
        //Returns values
        console.log(translate)
    }
    //Returns Empty String;

    console.log(translate)
    res.send(translate);
});
```

This time, the code will execute as you probably want. First, the `find` method will be called for word=hello, then, after the execution is finished, the `find` method will be called for word=love and finally after both calls are finished, the `res.send` will be called.